# Linq query syntax

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, inner-join

I have this linq query that appear to be good, haven't tested yet.
But I'm wondering why i can't put And statements on a separate line.
If i try I get and unexpected token error, and c and b become 
inaccessible dut to protection level
Working Query

```
Dim result =
                From b In context.H_Beneficiary
                         Join e In context.Employees
                         On b.EmployeeId Equals (e.EmployeeId)
                         Join c In context.Companies
                         On e.AncillaryId Equals (c.CompanyId)
                         Where e.AncillaryId.Equals(iPerId) And c.AncillaryId.Equals(iCompanyId) And ((b.EndDate Is Nothing) Or (b.EndDate.Equals(DateTime.Today)))
                         Select b.EnterTime


            Return CDate(result)


        Return CDate(result)
```

Desired Query

```
 Dim result =
                From b In context.H_Beneficiary
                         Join e In context.Employees
                         On b.EmployeeId Equals (e.EmployeeId)
                         Join c In context.Companies
                         On e.AncillaryId Equals (c.CompanyId)
                         Where e.AncillaryId.Equals(iPerId)
                         And c.AncillaryId.Equals(iCompanyId)
                         And ((b.EndDate Is Nothing) Or (b.EndDate.Equals(DateTime.Today)))
                         Select b.EnterTime
```

Comment: Because that's VB.Net syntax. Put a `_` at the end of the line and it will work though.

Comment: @asawyer Thanks that works, post below if you want the check ;)

Comment: I posted before seeing your comment - sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the implicit line continuations don't consider 'And'.
Just use an explicit line continuation on the previous line:

```
     From b In context.H_Beneficiary 
                 Join e In context.Employees 
                 On b.EmployeeId Equals (e.EmployeeId) 
                 Join c In context.Companies 
                 On e.AncillaryId Equals (c.CompanyId) 
                 Where e.AncillaryId.Equals(iPerId) _
                 And c.AncillaryId.Equals(iCompanyId) _
                 And ((b.EndDate Is Nothing) Or (b.EndDate.Equals(DateTime.Today))) 
                 Select b.EnterTime
```